# AccuRev doesn't install due to missing Java

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install AccuRev on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Java is installed. I got the following error:

```
./AccuRev_5_4_1_LinuxClientOnly_x86_2_4.bin: 3310: exec: /tmp/install.dir.3817/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found
```

It seems the bin file is extracted into a temp directory and then install from there but somehow there is no java found. I installed the java and other java programs running fine. java and javac link are also created in /usr/bin location. how can I make the installation use java installed in the system?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following and try again if you have the same or similar issue:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

got above from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-C7174M/index.html?product=PB&solution=1-C7174M).

Comment: This worked for me but the library has changed.
sudo apt-get install lib32z1